# Xcode - UIStoryboard black screen

Tags: objective-c, ios, uiviewcontroller, uistoryboard

I am using a `UIStoryboard`. I created my application empty, and then I added a storyboard. The storyboard is set as the main storyboard in the project settings and also as the 'Main Storyboard file base name' in the Info.plist.

My app delegate simply returns `YES` without any other code.

My `main.m` includes this line of code:

```
return UIApplicationMain(argc, argv, nil, NSStringFromClass([ARGAppDelegate class]));
```

I get this message in the console:

> Application windows are expected to have a root view controller at the
>   end of application launch

My view controller is in the UIStoryboard, as the initial view controller.

Just wondering what I am doing wrong here...

My AppDelegate code:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{        
    return YES;
}
```

Thats all the code I have, if you are using a storyboard you do not need to create a window right?

Thanks for the help, appreciated!

---

Update:

I actually changed my AppDelegate code, still does not make a difference:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    // Override point for customization after application launch.

    self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];

    UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"MainStoryboard_iPhone" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]];
    UIViewController *initViewController = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"ARGViewControllerID"];

    NSLog(@"%@", initViewController); // Returns a valid ARGViewController object

    [self.window setRootViewController:initViewController];
    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
    [self.window makeKeyWindow];

    return YES;
}
```

Comment: When I run into things like this starting from scratch, I find it easiest to compare to a 'known good' - in this case, try comparing your app to the autogenerated one for 'single page app' instead of 'empty' and see what's different that might cause your problem.

Comment: @Chris I have done that, I do not see anything wrong though

Comment: Well I assume there are some differences (as a single page app does not do that) - try applying changes to one or the other to make the projects look more similar until you find the change that is causing the problem.

Comment: @Chris I mean nothing that shouldn't work, ok I will do that, however my other project does not use a storyboard. Plus, I dont think there is any difference worth noticing except the app delegate, which is empty in this project (except for returning YES)

Comment: Can you add your `applicationDidFinishLaunching` method from the `AppDelegate` the `int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {}` has nothing to do with this error it maybe showing it is here because the exception hasn't been catched and this is the last place it can be catched.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Application windows are expected to have a root view controller at the end of application launch`

sounds like you hadn't embedded in a navigation controller at the beginning of your storyboard

Comment: I don't think storyboards require a navigation controller

Comment: didn't know that, i have no experience with storyboards

Comment: Yeah go to editor and embed in navigation controller and your away.  When you get used to it its much quicker and less code.

Answer (score 1):

When `-applicationDidFinishLaunching:withOptions:` does not set up a window or storyboard in code, the next place the system looks is in the info.plist for a default XIB or StoryBoard.  The 'Default Storyboard' field in your project info is either empty, or pointing at a non-existent .storyboard file.  Click your project in the tree then the 'Summary' tab and fill in the field with the name of your storyboard file.

Comment: I dont see a 'Default Storyboard' field anywhere.

Comment: This is what I was thinking but couldn't be sure.

Comment: My bad, it was the 'Summary' tab.  Editing now

Comment: In the project info, 'Main storyboard file base name' is correctly set. And in summary 'Main Storyboard' is correctly set :)

Comment: Hmph.  I'm actually at a loss.  Set up a view controller in code just to see if it goes away.  (this is why I hate storyboarding)

Answer (score 0):

Unable to find solution after digging through forums and questions and playing with the code, I switched to xibs. Been happy with it since 4 hours ago when I made the transition. I hope I never have to see another error-filled and hard-to-use storyboard file again!